# reset a two dimensional array via function in c language windows

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I want to reset a 2 dimensional board, but I'm not sure how to return a pointer to the array.
also I think there must be an easier way to reset it but can't find one.

```
char reset_board(int rows,int columns,char board[rows][columns])
{
    for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
        {
                board[i][j] == ' ';
        }
    }
    return &board[0][0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't have to return anything, you were working with a pointer to the array (array decays into pointer). So any changes you do will be reflected in the callee. If you are curious then know that 2d array `char s[ROW][COL]` decays into `char (*)[COL]` when passed to a function.

```
void reset_board(int rows,int columns,char board[rows][columns])
{
   ....   
}
```

This works.

Easier way is to use `memset`

```
memset(board,' ',sizeof board);
```

or

```
memset (board, ' ', rows * columns * sizeof **board);
```

**but this only works in the scope where it is declared as `char board[ROW][COL]`.**

---

Also `return &board[0][0];` this is returning address of `char` so it will be `char*` in type not `char`.

Comment: Or `memset (board, ' ', rows * columns * sizeof *board);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Check it once..edited. Thanks for suggestions and stopping by.

Comment: Yep, but leaving `sizeof *board` works if it is type `char`, `int`, `double` whatever `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Right you are.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Try printing the value of `rows * columns * sizeof *board`. It's not what you think it is.

Comment: @user3386109.: It's ok...I corrected and was checking `**board`

Comment: @user3386109.: I was checking in my machine and it will be `**board` to get to the `char`. `*board` will return `colsize` in case of char array..so it tries to set more than there is giving undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3386109 -- chuckling... duh... `sizeof **board` (it's late `:)` Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The irony is that the missing `*` would cause exactly the problem that `sizeof *ptr` is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @user3386109.: Well there is no 2d array in c...so it is basically array of arrays and by using single pointer we get to the that single dimensional aray (the first one) thats why sizeof returns `COL` in ccase of `char`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: I guess nobody finds this answer helpful...best to delete I guess or idk.